Why doesn't the id parameter update from the URL in my ASP.NET Core POST method?
I have a POST method in ASP.NET Core that takes an id parameter from the URL. When I change the id in the URL and submit the form, the id in the POST method does not reflect the updated value from the URL.
my view with prove that there is no Id field in my form.
@model GenreUpdateVM
<form method="post">
    <input asp-for="Name" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Name" style="color:red"></span>

    <button type="submit">Update</button>
    <a asp-action="index">Cancel</a>

</form>

in my get int id is coming from Route, am I right?
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Update(int id)
{
    var request = new RestRequest($"Genres/{id}", Method.Get);
    var response = await _restClient.ExecuteAsync<ApiResponseMessage<GenreUpdateVM>>(request);

    if (!response.IsSuccessful)
    {
        TempData["Err"] = response.Data.ErrorMessage;
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    return View(response.Data.Data);
}

from here to be precise
app.MapControllerRoute(
     name: "default",
     pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

what about my POST method?
[HttpPost]

public async Task<IActionResult> Update(int id, GenreUpdateVM vm)
{
    var request = new RestRequest($"Genres/{id}", Method.Put);
    request.AddJsonBody(vm);
    var response = await _restClient.ExecuteAsync<ApiResponseMessage<object>>(request);

    if (!response.IsSuccessful)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError(response.Data.PropertyName, response.Data.ErrorMessage);
        return View();
    }
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}

why when I change my id in the route, my POSTmethod still gets value from GET method?
for example: /Home/Update/4 this is how it looks like when I am in GET section, but then I change it to /Home/Update/10, and I am expecting the error because I do not have any by id 10, but it still updated the one with Id 4. Help me understand how routing and passing and binding works in ASP MVC.
Expected behaviour: after getting to view, I manually change id number from 4 to 10 on URL, so my POST method should get (int Id=10)
Actual behaviour: my change of Id does not affect id which passes to POST method. It still gets the old value which is 4.
Thanks in advance

I find it difficult to follow what the problems is. What is the 'error', and why are you expecting it? You may find it useful to edit the post and follow the usual bug report structure: 1. Steps to reproduce. 2. Expected behaviour. 3. Actual behaviour.

Thanks, I have added a short description of expected and actual behaviour. The problem is I do not completely understand who binding works in ASP MVC. Little research says that imput passed to POST method as parameters are taken from form values, but in my case there is no Id field in my form so it should take it from URL id value. But when I change my URL id value, it still takes the old one

Actually, when you post the request from the form tag by clicking the submit button, it will not add the url data automatically and you will not modify the post url.
The post url will just like post https://localhost:7072/home/update, the url parameter 10 which you provided from the get method will not added inside it.
To solve this issue, I suggest you could use viewbag to pass the id to the view, then using the input hidden field to store the id value, then the form tag post will add the id value when you click the button.
More details, you could refer to below example:
Controller:
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Update(int id)
    {
        //var request = new RestRequest($"Genres/{id}", Method.Get);
        //var response = await _restClient.ExecuteAsync<ApiResponseMessage<GenreUpdateVM>>(request);

        //if (!response.IsSuccessful)
        //{
        //    TempData["Err"] = response.Data.ErrorMessage;
        //    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        //}

        // Pass the id to the view
        ViewBag.Id = id;

        return View(/*response.Data.Data*/);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Update(int id, GenreUpdateVM vm)
    {
        //var request = new RestRequest($"Genres/{id}", Method.Put);
        //request.AddJsonBody(vm);
        //var response = await _restClient.ExecuteAsync<ApiResponseMessage<object>>(request);

        //if (!response.IsSuccessful)
        //{
        //    ModelState.AddModelError(response.Data.PropertyName, response.Data.ErrorMessage);
        //    return View(vm);  // Pass the model back to the view
        //}

        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

View:
@model GenreUpdateVM
<h1>Update</h1>


<form method="post">
    <!-- Add a hidden input field to pass the id -->
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@ViewBag.Id" />

    <input asp-for="Name" />
    <span asp-validation-for="Name" style="color:red"></span>

    <button type="submit">Update</button>
    <a asp-action="index">Cancel</a>
</form>

Result:


Thanks for an answer! However my question was not about how to fix this problem but rather from where my POST method get Id value?
[HttpPost]
public async Task Update(int id, GenreUpdateVM vm)
int id is passed to this method when I post my form without hidden id value. So the question is how?

If you are using the  URL /Home/Update/4 to access the update page and your form tag's action attribute value is null, when you click the submit button, it will post to the same url  URL /Home/Update/4. This is the reason why you the id is 4 inside the backend. The reason why you change the url  /Home/Update/10 inside the browser doesn't work is, this is not actually current url, you just modify it inside the browser without accessing it, so it will still post to the  /Home/Update/4.

Because form will send POST method to the default endpoint.
This means it would not have last part representing ID.
So, if you don't have already, you need Id property on your update view model GenreUpdateVM that will point to entity being updated, then you need to incorporate it inside the cshtml code:
<form method="post" action="home/update/@Model.Id">

This will use Model.Id to provide ID for the URL. Also you don't need to specify method="post" - it is by default.

if my default endpoint does not have Id value, so why when I post it takes Id value from GET? When I go to GET method I have this URL /Home/Update/4. Then when I click post my form int id in my POST method is still 4 even if change it before posting
